# A regex for letters and space that cannot be a whitespace

Tags: regex

I cannot figure out how to add two regex together, I have these requirements:

1. Letters and space `^[\p{L} ]+$`
2. Cannot be whitespace `^[^\s]+$`

I cannot figure out how to write one regex that will combine both? There is perhaps some other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?! +$)[\p{L} ]+$
^(?!\s+$)[\p{L}\s]+$
^\s*\p{L}[\p{L}\s]*$
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!\s+$)` - no 1 or more whitespaces are allowed till the end of the string
- `[\p{L}\s]+` - 1+ letters or whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wtHOxD/2).

The `^\s*\p{L}[\p{L}\s]*$` is a regex that matches any 0+ whitespaces at the start of the string, then requires a letter that it consumes, and then any 0+ letters/whitespaces may follow.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wtHOxD/1).